# Trying to subplot groups with date axis different methods

Tags: pandas, date, matplotlib

I got a DataFrame:

```
           date   phone        sensor pallet
126  2019-04-15  940203  C0382C391A4D     47
127  2019-04-15  940203  C0382D392A4D     47
133  2019-04-16  940203  C0382C391A4D     47
134  2019-04-16  940203  C0382D392A4D     47
138  2019-04-17  940203  C0382C391A4D     47
139  2019-04-17  940203  C0382D392A4D     47
144  2019-04-18  940203  C0382C391A4D     47
145  2019-04-18  940203  C0382D392A4D     47
156  2019-04-19  940203  C0382D392A4D     47
157  2019-04-19  940203  C0382C391A4D     47
277  2019-04-15  941557  C0392D362735     32
279  2019-04-15  941557  C03633364D50     32
286  2019-04-16  941557  C03633364D50     32
287  2019-04-16  941557  C0392D362735     32
296  2019-04-17  941557  C03633364D50     32
297  2019-04-17  941557  C0392D362735     32
305  2019-04-18  941557  C0392D362735     32
306  2019-04-18  941557  C03633364D50     32
317  2019-04-19  941557  C03633364D50     32
318  2019-04-19  941557  C0392D362735     32
561  2019-04-15  942316  C0384639224D     45
562  2019-04-15  942316  C03632364950     45
563  2019-04-15  942316  C03920363835     45
564  2019-04-15  942316  C0382939384D     45
573  2019-04-16  942316  C0382939384D     45
574  2019-04-16  942316  C0384639224D     45
575  2019-04-16  942316  C03632364950     45
```

i want to be able to make subplot for each pallet which contain the sensors arrived in each date.
example:

[image: plot example1]

### *i have tried few methods:*

#### ax.plot_date

looping through opened ax's and plotting through each 1

```
        grouped = pallets_arrived.groupby('pallet')

        nrows = 2
        ncols = 2
        fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols)

        targets = zip(grouped.groups.keys(), axs.flatten())
        for i, (key, ax) in enumerate(targets):
            ax.plot_date(grouped.get_group(key)['date'], grouped.get_group(key)['sensor'], 'o')
        plt.show()
        return pallets_arrived
```

which gives wierdly formatted repeating dates (index the Df with date isnt solving the prob)
[image: plot example1]

#### Df plotting

```
        grouped = pallets_arrived.groupby('pallet')
        nrows = 2
        ncols = 2
        fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols)

        targets = zip(grouped.groups.keys(), axs.flatten())
        for i, (key, ax) in enumerate(targets):
            grouped.get_group(key).plot(x='date', y='sensor', ax=ax)
        ax.legend()
        plt.show()
```

[image: plot example1]

or

```
    grouped = pallets_arrived.set_index('date').groupby('pallet')
    nrows = 2
    ncols = 2
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols)

    targets = zip(grouped.groups.keys(), axs.flatten())
    for i, (key, ax) in enumerate(targets):
        grouped.get_group(key).plot(grouped.get_group(key).index, y='sensor', ax=ax)
    ax.legend()
    plt.show()
```

[image: plot example1]

#### pyplot

```
        grouped = pallets_arrived.groupby('pallet')
        nrows = 2
        ncols = 2
        fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols)

        targets = zip(grouped.groups.keys(), axs.flatten())
        for i, (key, ax) in enumerate(targets):
            plt.sca(ax)
            plt.plot(grouped.get_group(key)['date'], grouped.get_group(key)['sensor'])
        ax.legend()
        plt.show()
```

which again
[image: plot example1]

#### Pivot pallets to Plot() on columns(pallets)

which doesnt work because there are more than 1 sensor in each pallet in same date. so there is a duplicated value error...

### I really dont know what method to use to make this 1 correct:

1. grouping similar dates in x axis.
2. being able to plot each pallet to different subplot.

i think i dont get the pandas wrapping of matplotlib correctly. 
ill be glad for some explenation because im reading guides and cant understand the preferred method for those stuff.

Thanks alot for the helpers.

Comment: it seems your main problem is that you are unhappy about the automatic datetime format chosen, i.e. the fact that `2019-04-15 12:00` is shown as `"04-15 12"`. You can choose your own format via `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))` or similar to your liking.

Comment: Its not that my friend. its that the same date  i.e 15/4/2019 is displayed multiple times only because there are several rows of information arrived at the same day. in example ( 15-4-00, 15-4-12 ( both represent 15/4/2019) ) .further more you can see that the information for 15/4/2019 is displayed only for 15-4-00 and not for the other versions.

Comment: i mean as you can see, time is not relevant and not part of the date in the table. am i worng somehow?

Comment: If Your axis goes from 0 to 20, there will be 10 ticked on the axis, independent of whether you have 10 in your data or not. The same principle applies here. So if the aim is to have daily ticks at midnight `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.dates.DayLocator())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `matplotlib` to plot categorical data:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use('ggplot')
%matplotlib inline

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(df['date'], df['sensor'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

or if you want to color the groups:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for _,g in df.groupby('pallet'):
    ax.scatter(g['date'], g['sensor'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

you can also add a legend:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for _,g in df.groupby('pallet'):
    ax.scatter(g['date'], g['sensor'], label='Pallet_'+str(_))
    ax.legend()
plt.show()
```